# Xcode 11 archive gives PhaseScriptExecution failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode11

After I migrate my project from swift 3.2 to swift 4 in Xcode 10 I try to archive in Xcode 11 and give me this error:

> PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script
>   /Users/desarrollo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-iOS-ewcyzseaubkujucenluznpmduhoo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp-iOS-DEV/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp-iOS.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApp-iOS-DEV.build/Script-E95AEDE51E54767F00B60429.sh
>   (in target 'MyApp-iOS-DEV' from project 'MyApp-iOS')
>
> . . .
>
> /Users/desarrollo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-iOS-ewcyzseaubkujucenluznpmduhoo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp-iOS-DEV/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp-iOS.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApp-iOS-DEV.build/Script-E95AEDE51E54767F00B60429.sh:
>   line 5: $(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION) + 1: syntax error: operand expected
>   (error token is "$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION) + 1")

In the error stack I find ***export CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION=114***

I don't have any script with "$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION) + 1" so I don't know what to do

Comment: There must be a bug in one of your scripts.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:**

This causes builds to be canceled! Have a look at S1LENT WARRIOR's answer below, it seems to be working better.

**UPDATE 1:**

In the latest version of Xcode (Version 11.1) you can do the build number auto increment fairly easily.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to your target's `Build Settings`
2. Search for `Versioning System`
3. Set it's value to `Apple Generic`
4. Go to your target's `Build Phases`
5. Add a new Run Script
6. Add the following line `agvtool next-version -all`

Do this for all your targets and their build numbers will all be synced and updated every time you run any of the targets.

*Got this answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58237340/1432355*

**P.S.: As said in a comment below**

> Using avgtool in a Run Script Phase causes the build to get cancelled

**ORIGINAL:**

You didn't do anything wrong I think.

If you go to your `info.plist` you will see that the build number has been replaced by `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)` (you can find the variable in the Build Settings tab).

I am guessing you are using a script that increments build number automatically and that is causing the issue (I have the same thing on my project right now).

If you remove that script your app should build without this error.

I haven't found a solution yet on how to make the script work with this new `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)` variable. (I will update this answer when I have found the solution)

Comment: Using `avgtool` in a Run Script Phase causes the build to get cancelled. Have you got any workaround this?

Comment: @Rafał Yes I noticed that too... I will go back to this next week and will update this answer (again..) once I've found a solution that really works

Comment: @OliverD If you go to your target's `Build Phases` tab and click on the 'plus' a the top you should have a popover with a button that says `New Run Script Phase`

Comment: @Moucheg Any solution for build getting canceled while archiving ?

Comment: @Anuraj nop didn't find anything that works unfortunately...

Comment: This solution work on Xcode Version 12.2 (12B45b), Thx

Comment: I was using this in my post actions in the scheme. Does not cancel the build

Comment: @theReverend Hmm maybe they made some updated that fix that issue. Need to check again. What is your xcode version ?

Comment: I’m using Xcode 12.3, it still cancels the build for me in phases, still works as a post action

Comment: @theReverend Thanks, I'll investigate over the weekend

Answer (score 12):

All the above answers weren't doing the trick by themselves, I had to compute a bunch of them, including the Apple documentation (see references below). So here are the steps I did if it helps someone to have all the steps.

**In Info.plist, set:**

- CFBundleShortVersionString to $(MARKETING_VERSION)
- CFBundleVersion to $(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)

**In target build settings:**

- set Versioning System to "Apple Generic"
- set Current Project Version to 1 (or whatever version you want)
- set Marketing Version to 1.0.0 (or whatever version you want)

**In the scheme > Archive:**

- add a post-action "Run Script Action":

  - Provide build settings from: your app
  - in the script:
    `cd ${PROJECT_DIR} ; xcrun agvtool next-version -all ;`

---

1. Apple doc mentioned by [cuimingda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5563533/cuimingda) : 
   https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1827/_index.html
2. Some of the steps mentioned by [moucheg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432355/moucheg)

Comment: I followed exactly the same steps. But the Archive keeps cancelling. I am using Xcode 11. Any solution to avoid the cancelling of archive?

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly - except, I had to change **Bundle Version** to a random number, for example **1**. When I did `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)` it didn't work.

Comment: I've got three apps - one is totally fine with $(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION) but the other two instantly fail to build - entering a literal value for the Bundle Version sorted the two that wouldn't build.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the script that worked for me on `Xcode 11+`
Just add a new `Run Script Phase` to your `Build Phases`
Add it below the `Link Binary with Libraries` phase.

```
#!/bin/sh

# To make executable, use: chmod u+x Build-Versioning-Scripts/Increment_Build_Number.sh
# to locate your target's info.plist use
# ${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}

echo "----"
echo "Info.plist for target: ${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}"

buildNum=$(/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH}")
echo "Current build #: $buildNum"

if [ -z "$buildNum" ]; then
echo "No build number found in $PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH"
exit 2
fi

buildNum=$(expr $buildNum + 1)
echo "Build # incremented to: $buildNum"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNum" "$PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH"
echo "----"
exit 0
```

This script was originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55525399/634958) by [Alex Zavatone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1058199/alex-zavatone).

Hope this helps

Comment: This perfectly works! All the solutions related to avg tools is making the archive getting cancelled. This worked for me in Xcode 11.

Answer (score 5):

Just change CFBundleVersion from `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)` to number, in my case is `1000` in Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1004</string>
```

Then the shell will be OKey:

```
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

Comment: and if you want to modify current_project_version, you can find answer at apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1827/_index.html