# How to script to update bundle version?

Tags: ios, scripting, watchos

I have an iOS app that currently use this script in `Build Phases` to update bundle version when archive.

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

Now that I need to add a dependence watchOS app. My watch app is written with `SwiftUI` while my iOS app is `UIKit`. I'm using `Xcode 14.2`.

I also need to have this process of update watch app version to the same as iOS when archive.
After several tried and error,

like,

- using PlistBuddy to update both iOS & watchOS's `info.plist`.

```
buildNumber=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
watchOSPlist=$(path/to/watchOS/plist)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_PATH"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$watchOSPlist"
```

This has issue: iOS is archived with correct app version, but watchOS always wrong app version.

- using AgvTool to update both `Plist` and `Current Project Version` .

```
buildNumber=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
agvtool new-version -all $buildNumber
exit 0
```

This has issue that the build is always canceled. Exactly same issue here:

[Archive in Xcode 4.5 - No errors, but build cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869159/archive-in-xcode-4-5-no-errors-but-build-cancelled)
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5075181

It seems that:

> The iOS app takes the version from the `Info.plist` 's Bundle Version, while the watchOS app takes the version from `Project Setting` > `Build Setting` > `Current Project Version`

So now I set as bellow:

Set `Info.plist`'s `bundle version` to `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`, the just use agvtool as pre-action - archive scheme 's script

```
buildNumber=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
agvtool new-version $buildNumber
exit 0
```

`-all` will modify the plist, so I remove the `-all`, it will just modify the project file.

to modify before archive, but the actual result is, it archives first and then change the version later, resulting wrong version in archive.

So what can I do to make this happen?

I expect a script to change the version of both iOS & watchOS to the same number for archiving.